# Synthetic network graph

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I am trying to validate a system to detect more than 2 cluster in a  network graph. For this i need to create a synthetic graph with some cluster. The graph should be very large, more than 100k nodes at least. I s there any system to do this? Any known dataset with more than 2 cluster would also be suffice.

Comment: can you clearly define what is meant by "cluster"?

Comment: A part of graph whose density is high and have low cut from e rest of the graph.

Answer (score 0):

If you stick to `networkx`, you can generate two large complete graphs with `nx.complete_graph()`, merge them, and then add some edges connecting randomly chosen nodes in each graph. If you want a more realistic example, build dense `nx.erdos_renyi_graph()`s instead of the complete graphs.

Comment: Any constructive comments from the downvoter will be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for your hints. I will try those. No idea why you down voted.